# android.view.InflateException en mi onCreate del MainActivity (Android Java)

Tags: java, android

A las buenas, a ver, estaba observando la consola de Google Play y me ha reportado el siguiente error desde una tablet:

```
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException:

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
  at com.isaac.tiquismiquis.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:211)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6284)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1113)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2518)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException:

  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:782)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:

  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:2834)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2756)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:870)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:152)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:140)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:72)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:68)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:746)
```

Buscando información, sospecho que este error es debido a la densidad de la pantalla de la tablet (son 8 pulgadas), ya que en el onCreate tengo para que cuando pulsa un botón y el `edittext` está vacío, cambie la imagen por otra, o directamente es que he añadido la imagen en un solo tamaño, ya que solo la añadí en uno de ellos "a pelo" en la carpeta `drawable`.

Voy a poneros también el contenido del onCreate de mi MainActivity y el contenido del XML, por si hubiera cualquier error en el:

Aquí tenéis por un lado el contenido del XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logotipo"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textNoTranslate"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/truenosbd"
            android:textColor="#6D6D6D"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivLogo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBeforeTranslate"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/truenoultlt"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBeforeTranslate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTranslate"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="@font/truenosbd"
            android:background="@color/buttons"
            android:text="Traducir"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/btnVoice"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etBeforeTranslate" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVoice"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/buttons"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_voice"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnTranslate"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etBeforeTranslate" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y por otro lado os pongo el contenido del onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    btnVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (count == 0) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    checkPermission();

                } else {

                    speechToText();
                    btnVoice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_voice_press);
                    etBeforeTranslate.setText("");
                    etBeforeTranslate.setHint("Venga anda, te escucho, mimimi...");
                }

                count = 1;

            } else if (count == 1) {

                mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
                btnVoice.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_voice);
                etBeforeTranslate.setHint("");
                count = 0;

            }
        }
    });

    btnTranslate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String texto = textTranslate();

            if (etBeforeTranslate.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logotipoangry);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡Ay que agobio! Intridici il tixti, anda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Translates = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Translates");
                registerTranslates();
                ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logotipo);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TranslateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("texto", texto);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        }
    });

}
```

A ver si me podéis echar una mano con esto y si después de todo mis sospechas eran ciertas, la verdad que en mi corta andanza por el mundo de la programación, nunca había ejecutado mi app más que en mi móvil, pero claro ahora que la he subido a la store, me salen otros fallos, aunque me viene bien para aprender. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Has conseguido reproducir el error en local? Girando el dispositivo y forzando el error?

Comment: Tengo bloqueado el giro de la aplicación desde el Manifest

Comment: El fallo entiendo que te ha dado a ti? o a otro usuario de la app? En cualquier caso que versión y modelo de Android esta/s usando? Como dices seguramente son las dimensiones que se esta usando en un dispositivo en el que se salen de la pantalla y al buscarlos da el crash

Comment: El error se lo ha dado a un usuario, en la versión 6 de Android y es una tablet BQ M8.

Comment: Usa dimensiones relativas en lugar de definir las a mano para descartar el error

Comment: Me parece que intenta buscar el `Layout` i/o dimensiones para tablet y no las consigue, eso por esta linea del error `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:`

Comment: ¿Y esto como o donde podría añadírselo?

Comment: En tu LogCat deberías buscar donde indica en que linea del xml se presenta el error para saber que recurso falta, esto me parece que es debido a que tu dispositivo no encuentra el recurso. @Isaac

Comment: Encontré lo que me pasaba en esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477979/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f07006e

Comment: @Isaac no olvides agregar la imagen adecuada en cada folder, a menos que agregues la imagen en el directorio /drawable este problema no se presentaría, pero lo adecuado es agregar las imágenes correspondientes en cada directorio  /drawable-....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> la consola de Google Play y me ha reportado el siguiente error desde
>   una tablet

**Esto indica que el error ocurre en ciertos dispositivos**

Ahora en cuanto a el mensaje de error del stacktrace, este i**ndica que no existe un recurso el cual intenta cargarse desde un layout**:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

---

Debes revisar que la misma imagen se encuentre en todos los directorios `/drawable` que tienen sufijos, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El problema se debe a que en alguno de estos directorios `/drawable-...` falta una imagen requerida para cierta densidad/tamaño de dispositivo.**

---

Si deseas evitar esto, una opción es agregar todas las imágenes en el directorio `/drawable` y cualquier densidad/tamaño de dispositivo la obtendría sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque lo correcto es definitivamente agregar la imagen requerida en cada directorio para que se visualice correctamente de acuerdo a su tamaño/densidad.

---

Revisar:

[**Cómo brindar compatibilidad con diferentes densidades de píxeles**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html?hl=es)

[**Agregar gráficos vectoriales de varias densidades**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html?hl=es)

Comment: Vale, dos cosas: la primera es me siento confuso, ¿te has cambiado el nombre? y la segunda es: ¿existe algún tipo de guía para saber que tamaño es el adecuado para meter en cada carpeta drawable?

Comment: Primera pregunta) Si! , Segunda Pregunta) Si, en la documentación se muestra información acerca de medidas de recursos para cada directorio /drawable  : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html?hl=es